# How to run two profiles in one maven command?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-profiles

I have a pom.xml file having surefire:test plugin and have two profiles to run diffrent test modules/tests. Iam trying to run these by command "mvn surefire:test -PfirstProfile,secondProfile".
But here only the second profile written in pom.xml gets executed. This command is recommended by apache maven website. Here is my pom.xml file:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.plugin.surefire.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <forkMode>always</forkMode>
      <!-- <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore> -->
      <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
      <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
      <runOrder>${testRunOrder}</runOrder>
    </configuration>
    </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <profile>
  <id>firstProfile</id>
  <properties>
        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
  </properties>
  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>${maven.plugin.surefire.version}</version>
              <configuration>
                  <includes>
                    <include>**/AbcTest.java</include>
                  </includes>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>

  </build>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>SecondProfile</id>
  <properties>
        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
  </properties>
  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>${maven.plugin.surefire.version}</version>

              <configuration>
                  <includes>
                      <include>**/xyzTest.java</include>                      
                  </includes>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>

  </build>
</profile>
```

so how do i run both these profiles together? I tried execution IDs also. But it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the configuration for maven-surefire-plugin in both profiles like this:

```xml
   <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>${maven.plugin.surefire.version}</version>
              <configuration>
                  <includes combine.children="append">
                    <include>**/AbcTest.java</include>
                  </includes>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>

  </build>
```

Apart from this it's not a good idea to select unit tests by profiles. If those tests are integration test you should go with maven-failsafe-plugin instead.

Comment: @khkhmarbaise Basically, my first profile is for all Unit Tests where i include **/*Test.java and exclude **/*IntegrationTest.java. And second profile is for all Integration Tests where i exclude **/*Test.java and include **/*IntegrationTest.java. Theses two profiles i am using in my test_runner.sh script to run unit tests and integration tests when developers specify -u or -i option respectively. But i also want to run both unit and integration tests when developer specifies -u and -i options both. And that is why i was trying to run both profiles in one maven command.

Comment: Continuing my above comment..Which is resulting into running only one profile which is last in pom.xml file. If this problem gets solved by maven-failsafe-plugin you mentioned, please let me know. Or if you have another solution, pease specify. And the combine.children="append" solution you mentioned, its not working for me. Thanks for your quick reply

Comment: If you are working with unit tests by the naming convention /*Test.java or /*TestCase.java or /Test*.java which is handled by maven-surefire-plugin automatically. If you like having integration tests you should follow the naming conventions and use `IT*.java`, `*IT.java` or `*ITCase.java` which is supported out of the box by maven-failsafe-plugin. If you follow the conventions you don't need configuration (Convention over Configuration paradigm).